# Windows SIM was unable to generate a catalog file

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-installation, answerfile

When I create catalog file using Windows System Image Manager (SIM), it eventually errors out that

> "Windows SIM was unable to generate a catalog file....."

Full Error message screen shot here.

[image]

The logfile contents are here:

```
1:44 PM : This application requires version 10.0.17134.1 of the Windows ADK.
Install this version to correct the problem
1:44 PM : 
1:44 PM : Windows SIM was unable to generate a catalog. For troubleshooting assistance, see the topic: 'Windows System Image Manager Technical Reference' in the Windows ADK User's Guide.
1:44 PM : 
1:44 PM : System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): Unknown error (0xc1420127)

Server stack trace: 
   at Microsoft.ComponentStudio.ComponentPlatformInterface.WimImageInfo.PreCreateCatalog()
   at Microsoft.ComponentStudio.ComponentPlatformInterface.OfflineImageInfo.CreateCatalog()
   at Microsoft.ComponentStudio.ComponentPlatformInterface.CatalogCreatorImpl.CreateCatalog(OfflineImageInfo offlineImageInfo)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at Microsoft.ComponentStudio.ComponentPlatformInterface.ICatalogCreator.CreateCatalog(OfflineImageInfo offlineImageInfo)
   at Microsoft.ComponentStudio.CatalogGenerator.CreateCat(ProgressDialog pd, Object o)
```

Microsoft [documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2524737/error-message-windows-sim-was-unable-to-generate-a-catalog-or-paramete) of this doesn't quite help since I am using x64 version of SIM on Windows 10 x64 (I don't even know where to get x86 version).

I tried the same steps on another Windows 10 x64 system and I was able to create catalog file using the same process.

My question is why exactly am I getting this error? Secondly even though it fails but it does create the catalog file in the directory. I can actually select it in Windows SIM and load it fine and also create new answer file. But is it incomplete or missing components or might have other issues?

The host PC is Windows 10 1803.

Windows SIM comes as part of Windows Assessment and Deployment Kit, here is a snapshot of installation of that.

[image]

There is no way to tell if its x64 version or x32 but I downloaded it from [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/get-started/adk-install). Even that doesn't say which architecture, this is the only link for Win10.

**Update**

I uninstalled Windows ADK and reinstalling it. I noticed it picks c:\Program Files **(x86)**\Windows Kits.... so it is the 32 bit version. How do I get 64 bit version of ADK?

Comment: The fact you have the 64-bit `Windows System Image Manager` isn't relevant to your problem.  The only reason it would be relevant is if you were trying to create a 32-bit catalog using the 64-bit version (which can only create 64-bit catalog files).  Is that the case?  **`Windows System Image Manager` is contained within the **Deployment Tools** contained within a given version of Windows ADK.**  While a file was created, it does not contain the files it should, the error indicates in no certain terms the file is incomplete.

Comment: @Ramhound I am creating catalog for 64 bit image as well and that's why the error is confusing. There is no part of 32 bit in any of it.

Comment: "as well" - indicates you intend to create a 32-bit and 64-bit image but that is only possible with the 32-bit application.  So what version of the Windows ADK do you have installed?  You should edit your question instead of submitting a comment answering this question.

Comment: @Ramhound Sorry the "as well" might have come out the wrong way. I mean both host PC and catalog file I am creating are 64 bit. I am not creating 32 bit catalog. I have added more info to my post though.

Comment: Since multiple versions of the Windows ADK are linked on that page, can you confirm your using the `Windows 10, 1809 ADK`?  "How do I get 64-bit version of ADK?" - You should already have it installed and it should be in the Program Files directory.

Comment: @Ramhound that's what I had installed initially but given my version is 1803, I uninstalled it and reinstalled the ADK for 1803 version which is listed in the link I posted but same results and getting same error.

Comment: So you should specify that information in the question body.

Comment: @Ramhound It seems it is now a different issue so I asked a new question [here](https://superuser.com/q/1391590/475817)

Comment: Since this question is still unanswered, it would be helpful if you provided the entire error message as a screenshot, that includes "Windows SIM was unable to generate a catalog file....." in the question body.

Comment: @Ramhound Added, as well as contents of log file it generates.

Comment: "This application requires version 10.0.17134.1 of the Windows ADK." - Based on that message it does not appear you have the correct version of Windows ADK.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87968/discussion-between-ramhound-and-zar).

Answer (score 1):

In my case using the 1903 version solved the same issue.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/get-started/what-s-new-in-kits-and-tools

> **Windows System Image Manager known issue**
>
> When using Window System Image Manager (SIM), you might encounter errors if the ADK is installed on a device running a 64-bit version of Windows. To create unattended Windows Setup answer files on a 64-bit version of Windows, download the WSIM 1903 update, and follow the included installation instructions.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error as well for the 1903 version. I went back to the page I downloaded the ADK installer from and noticed there was an update. After downloading in the update and following the instructions, the error went away and I was able to generate catalog file.

original download page:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/get-started/adk-install

link to update:
Download the Windows System Image Manager (WSIM) 1903 update
https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2095334

Comment: Windows System Image Manage and Windows Assessment and Deployment Kit are two entirely different things.  Both have not been updated since 1903 was released (Windows 1909 specific version of ADK was not released).