# How to download 64 bit version Windows Assessment and Deployment Kit for Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, 64-bit, 32-bit

[This](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/get-started/adk-install) is the page where one can download Windows ADK for Windows 10 but there is no way to select the version, 64 bit or 32 bit.

I thought, at least the default might be 64 bit which is what I need but when I download it, windows selects `C:\Program Files (x86)\` path which means this is 32 bit version. There is no other way I can tell which architecture is this for.

[image]

How can I download 64 bit version of Windows ADK for Windows 10 1803?

Comment: "There is no other way I can tell which architecture is this for" - Besides looking at the Task Manager for one of the includes executables.  To my knowledge there isn't a separate 64-bit, Which architectures  Windows SIM can support is entirely based on the OS it's being ran on.  *Your previous issue isn't connected to the architecture of the tools contained within Windows ADK.*  If you want to be able to service both 32-bit and 64-bit images, then your only choice, is to use a 32-bit OS.

Answer (score 0):

Installation folder is not related with bitness of the tools. Windows ADK needs Windows Kits folder for other associated tools and files. SO, it chooses `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Windows Assessment Toolkit` folder as default. You can find Windows ADK tools with different architecture in the folder as follows:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Windows Assessment Toolkit
│
├───amd64
│   └───Goals
├───arm
│   └───Goals
├───arm64
│   └───Goals
├───Content based Assessments
│   ├───amd64
│   ├───arm
│   ├───arm64
│   ├───Content
│   └───x86
├───Energy
│   ├───amd64
│   ├───arm
│   ├───arm64
│   ├───modules
│   ├───resources
│   └───x86
...
```

Answer (score 0):

> I thought, at least the default might be 64 bit which is what I need but when I download it, windows selects C:\Program Files (x86)\ path which means this is a 32-bit version.

There is not a 64-bit version of the Windows Assessment and Deployment Kit.  `Windows System Image Manager` (Windows SIM) uses a supplied Windows Image (.wim) file.

- 64-bit versions of Windows can only handle images that support x64-based systems.
- 32-bit versions of Windows can handle images that support x64-based, x84-based, and ARM-based systems.

[image]

Source: [Windows Image Files and Catalog Files Overview](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/desktop/wsim/windows-image-files-and-catalog-files-overview)

> There is no other way I can tell which architecture is this for.

You can determine the bitness of any process with Task Manager.  32-bit applications, running on a 64-bit operating systems, will be clearly labeled as 32-bit.