# WSIM - unable to generate catalog (still after fix)

Tags: sim, mdt, adk

I have been reading a lot of posts saying, there were problems creating the .clg file when using WSIM in 1903, but it should be fixed after the fix has been published by Microsoft. I still have problems though. I have done a fresh install of Windows 10 Pro installed ADK, the fix and generally just been following the amazing guide from [ceos3c](https://www.ceos3c.com/sysadmin/create-generalized-windows-10-image-deploy-fog-server/). When I try to make a catalog file at the end part 7 I get this from the log:

```
15:46 : This application requires version 10.0.18362.1 of the Windows ADK.
Install this version to correct the problem
15:46 : 
15:46 : Windows SIM was unable to generate a catalog. For troubleshooting assistance, see the topic: 'Windows System Image Manager Technical Reference' in the Windows ADK User's Guide.
15:46 : 
15:46 : System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): Unknown error (0xc1420127)

Server stack trace: 
   ved Microsoft.ComponentStudio.ComponentPlatformInterface.WimImageInfo.PreCreateCatalog()
   ved Microsoft.ComponentStudio.ComponentPlatformInterface.OfflineImageInfo.CreateCatalog()
   ved Microsoft.ComponentStudio.ComponentPlatformInterface.CatalogCreatorImpl.CreateCatalog(OfflineImageInfo offlineImageInfo)
   ved System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)
   ved System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   ved System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   ved System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   ved Microsoft.ComponentStudio.ComponentPlatformInterface.ICatalogCreator.CreateCatalog(OfflineImageInfo offlineImageInfo)
   ved Microsoft.ComponentStudio.CatalogGenerator.CreateCat(ProgressDialog pd, Object o)
15:46 : 
15:46 : Windows SIM was unable to generate a catalog. For troubleshooting assistance, see the topic: 'Windows System Image Manager Technical Reference' in the Windows ADK User's Guide.
15:46 : 
15:46 : System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): Unknown error (0xc1420127)

Server stack trace: 
   ved Microsoft.ComponentStudio.ComponentPlatformInterface.WimImageInfo.PreCreateCatalog()
   ved Microsoft.ComponentStudio.ComponentPlatformInterface.OfflineImageInfo.CreateCatalog()
   ved Microsoft.ComponentStudio.ComponentPlatformInterface.CatalogCreatorImpl.CreateCatalog(OfflineImageInfo offlineImageInfo)
   ved System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)
   ved System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   ved System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   ved System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   ved Microsoft.ComponentStudio.ComponentPlatformInterface.ICatalogCreator.CreateCatalog(OfflineImageInfo offlineImageInfo)
   ved Microsoft.ComponentStudio.CatalogGenerator.CreateCat(ProgressDialog pd, Object o)
```

I have been reading [this thread](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/df7f8b10-da83-47cd-8eb6-607e37568bf0/windows-10-1903-sim-tool-in-adk-101183621-fails-to-generate-catalogs-correctly-for-x64?forum=win10itprosetup) at TechNet from Microsoft which suggests I am not the only one, but also that the fix did the trick for most people.
I can also see [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1390699/windows-sim-was-unable-to-generate-a-catalog-file), which is not answered.

Any ideas to what I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you're using an install.wim (not install.esd)
2. .clg creation WITHIN MDT (when opening unattend.xml from MDT UI) still won't work. You have to open your unattend files from WSIM
3. Is this the fix you have followed? Because this is what always fixes it for me:

*Download https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2095334, extract the files, do not run the .bat script, but copy the two .exe files and overwrite the original WSIM executables with them.*